# How to kill a $\Sigma_{n+1}$-correct cardinal softly ($n>1$)?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals

A cardinal $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_n$-correct iff $V_\kappa \prec_n V$. For n>1, how to force a $\Sigma_{n+1}$-correct cardinal to be $\Sigma_{n}$-correct but not $\Sigma_{n+1}$-correct?

For $n=1$, we can force GCH below $\kappa$ and then violate GCH at $\kappa$.

If we assume some large cardinals, there are more partial answers, but the general situation is not clear to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very interesting question!

My student Erin Carmody (PhD 2015) had asked this question in
connection with her dissertation, [Force to change large cardinal
strength](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03432), which contains many
such killing-them-softly results. Her theorem 20 is the
$\Sigma_2$-reflecting cardinal case that you mention. I recall that
at the time we looked into the general $\Sigma_n$-reflecting case,
but it was left open in her dissertation.

How nice finally to have an answer to this.

**Theorem.** If $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_n$-correct, then there is a
class forcing extension preserving this in which $\kappa$ is not
$\Sigma_{n+1}$-correct.

**Proof.** Suppose that $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_n$ correct, where
$n>1$. By forcing, if necessary, let me assume that V=HOD holds and
more specifically that there is a $\Delta_2$-definable
well-ordering of the universe. Indeed, let us arrange this
specifically by forcing to code every set into the GCH pattern on a
certain definable sequence of coding points. This forcing preserves
correctness.

Consider the forcing notion $\text{Add}(\kappa,1)$, which is
definable in $V_\kappa$, and consider the dense sets for this
forcing that are $\Sigma_n$-definable in $V_\kappa$. I claim that
there is a subset $s\subset\kappa$ that is $\Sigma_n$ definable in
$V_\kappa$ and generic over $V_\kappa$ with respect to
$\Sigma_n$-definable dense classes for this forcing, meaning that
the initial segments of $s$ meet every $\Sigma_n$-definable dense
subset of this forcing.

If $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then this is easier to see, since in
this case the forcing is $<\kappa$-closed and one can simply meet
the dense sets one by one, using a definable enumeration of them. A
careful version of this argument works even when $\kappa$ is
singular, using the fact that $\kappa$ is $\Sigma_n$-correct. One
simply meets the dense sets one-by-one, and at limits, the
condition produced must be bounded below $\kappa$, since otherwise
one would have a $\Sigma_n$-definable singularization of $\kappa$,
which would violate correctness.

Now let us force with $\text{Add}(\newcommand\Ord{\text{Ord}}\Ord,1)$ to add a generic class
$S\subset\Ord$ extending $s$. (We could also have used a definable
$\Sigma_{n+1}$-generic class, without forcing.) In $V[S]$, let
$\mathbb{P}$ be the class forcing Easton support $\Ord$-iteration
that forces to code $S$ into the GCH pattern at another definable
sequence of ordinals that does not interfere with coding used
above.

Let $V[S][G]$ be the final extension. I claim that $\kappa$ remains
$\Sigma_n$-correct, since if a $\Sigma_n$-statement $\varphi(a)$ is
true in $V[S][G]$ about some parameter $a\in
V_\kappa[s][G_\kappa]$, then this is forced over $V[S][G]$ by some
condition, and by the correctness of $\kappa$ and the
$\Sigma_n$-genericity of $s$, it follows that it holds in
$V_\kappa[s][G_\kappa]$ as desired. Basically, we are lifting the
relation $V_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_n} V$ to
$V[s][G_\kappa]\prec_{\Sigma_n}V[S][G]$.

But I claim that $\kappa$ is not $\Sigma_{n+1}$-correct in
$V[S][G]$. Note that $V$ is $\Sigma_2$-definable in $V[S][G]$ using
the first sequence of coding points, and $V[S][G]$ thinks that $S$,
which is $\Sigma_2$-definable, is not $\Sigma_n$-definable in $V$,
since in fact it was generic over $V$. But $V_\kappa[s][G_\kappa]$
thinks that $s$ is $\Sigma_n$-definable in $V_\kappa$. This
violates $\Sigma_{n+1}$-correctness. $\Box$

Comment: Since this argument is a bit finicky, I wonder whether one might try something simpler. For example, suppose we just code the $\Sigma_2$-correct cardinals into the GCH pattern? Does this make $\Sigma_{n+1}$-correctness into mere $\Sigma_n$ correctness for all larger $n$? My idea is to drop down the complexity from the bottom, rather than from the top.